# Angular 4 - Focus on next element with Enter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, angular-forms

this question has been asked before for AngularJS and Jquery however I need to do this in Angular 4 and its slightly different.

Situation:

I have a component with a table (Tablecomponent). The table is filled with input fields for users. Now I want to tab through these input fields with Enter Key as well instead of Tab Key only.

I have found this solution somewhere else but it doesnt work because "element" has no function "focus()"

```
onKeyUp($event) {
if ($event.keyCode === 13) {
  const element: any = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling;
  if (element == null) {
    return;
  } else {
    element.focus();
  }
```

I'm not sure but I believe the first thing to do is to get the next Element ("input" field here) and simply "focus" it.

Answer (score 2):

Angular have a element reference [elementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) you can use and it will be more accurate to hit an event like `key` event in angular application.

```
// add it to your compoenent
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
```

Then you can focus it using

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should add some additional info. 
My test table is created dynamically with an ngFor loop.
What I've noticed is, I cant get to recognize the next element in the table (sibling, child). Whenever I press Enter, it will return null. However it does find a next element (next input field) if I created all the input fields one by one in the html.